# Angular Slick not starting (using JSON Data)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, slick.js

Guys AngularJS newbie here. 
I'm trying to aply Angular Slick to my Div.
I have fetching the image from SQL to JSON (succeeded).
Its only display as static image, slideshow not starting.
Any mistake did i make?

I have tried init-onload, i'm using slick jquery(version) for slick.js .
And i too load the angular-slick version.

I just follow the Instruction Manual from devmark. [github](https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel)

**I also have tried Slick Jquery version only and remove the Angular Slick, its still not working**

Please help mee...

**My scirpt and style**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/slick.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/slick.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-slick.min.js"></script>
```

**my HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AliceController" class="talent-container">
        <div ng-repeat="talent in talents" class="card boxed" ng-class=" {{talent.indexing}}">
<div class="media">
        <slick infinite=true slides-to-show=3 slides-to-scroll=3 data="awesomeThings">
            <div><img id="slideShow" ng-src="{{talent.images}}"></div>
            <div class="hide">
                <img id="slideShow" ng-src="{{talent.images02}}"></div>
            <div class="hide"><img id="slideShow" ng-src="{{talent.images03}}"></div>
        </slick>
        <button ng-click="slickConfig.method.slickPrev()">slickPrev()</button>
        <button ng-click="slickConfig.method.slickNext()">slickNext()</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**my app.js**

```
var alice = angular
        .module('alice', ['slickCarousel'])
        .controller('AliceController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.slickConfig = {
                enabled: true,
                autoplay: true,
                draggable: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 500
            };
            //            this is where the JSON from api.php is consumed
            $http.get('api.php').
            then(function (res) {
                // here the data from the api is assigned to a variable named users
                $scope.talents = res.data.talents;

            });
        }]).config(['slickCarouselConfig', function (slickCarouselConfig) {
            slickCarouselConfig.dots = true;
            slickCarouselConfig.autoplay = false;
  }]);
```

Comment: Please create a plnkr/fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You haven't included the `settings` attribute on the `<slick>` element and in the global configuration, `autoplay` is set to `false`.